# What Bible passage contains Satan and God where God rebukes Satan?

Tags: satan

I'm thinking of a Bible passage where the narrator has a dream/vision of being before the throne of God. Satan accuses him of being a sinner and unworthy and then God rebukes Satan and tells him to keep silent.

I can remember reading that story, but I don't remember where. Try as I might, I can't find it. Does anyone know where that story appears?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about verse identification. This type of question is off-topic by today's site standards: [Where's the line with the "verse-identification" tag?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4200)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be thinking of Zechariah:

> Then he showed me Joshua the high priest standing before the angel of the LORD, and Satan standing at his right hand to accuse him.  And the LORD said to Satan, "The LORD rebuke you, O Satan! The LORD who has chosen Jerusalem rebuke you! Is not this a brand plucked from the fire?"
>
> Zechariah 3:1-2 (RSV)

Comment: ah... I forgot about that one.

Comment: hmm. That must be the one. I thought it actually recounted Satan's accusation, but other than that this is exactly what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're thinking about the story of [Job](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=job1-2&version=ESV) but you have the story mixed a bit.